# PHP OOP AJAX, getting errors from Controller

Tags: php, ajax, oop, model-view-controller

first of all, sorry for my english.
Well,  I'm new to OOP PHP. I tried to develope a simple project and I would like to load data with Ajax to view changes without reloading pages.

I don't post models because they work fine and I can get all data I need.

But I have problems sending Controller errors and displaying them to the client.

I have a view called "viewUser.php" = main view.
In the main view is loaded "listUsers.php" in a div by an ajax call to display all the users, than each user has a button to send to another ajax call the id so this last ajax call can populate modal body with all the user informations in a form so they could be modified.
In this way all changes to user informations are displayed without reload the page but only with a ajax call in realtime.

I have this controller:

```
public function editUsers()
{
    $data = [
        'id' => '',
        'name' => '',
        'surname' => '',
        'privilege' => '',
        'position' => '',
        'verified' => '',
        'email' => ''
];

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $id = filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $surname = filter_var($_POST['surname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $privilege = filter_var($_POST['privilege'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $position = filter_var($_POST['position'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $verified = filter_var($_POST['verified'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        $data = [
            'id' => trim($id),
            'name' => trim($name),
            'surname' => trim($surname),
            'privilege' => trim($privilege),
            'position' => trim($position),
            'verified' => trim($verified),
            'email' => trim($email),
            ];


        $nameValidation = "/^[a-zA-Z]*$/";

        //Valida il nome
        if (empty($name)) {
            $error['nameError'] = 'Perfavore, inserisci il tuo nome!';
        } elseif (!preg_match($nameValidation, $name)) {
            $error['nameError'] = 'Il nome può contenere solo lettere!';
        }

        //Controlla che gli errori siano vuoti
        if (empty($error['nameError'])) {
            $this->userManagementModel->editUser($data);
        }
    }}
```

called by ajax

```
function ajaxEditUser() {
$(document).on("click", "#editUser", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $.trim($('#floatingInputId').val());
    var name = $.trim($('#floatingInputName').val());
    var surname = $.trim($('#floatingInputSurname').val());
    var email = $.trim($('#floatingInputEmail').val());
    var password = $.trim($('#floatingInputPassword').val());
    var confirmPassword = $.trim($('#floatingInputConfirmPassword').val());
    var privilege = $.trim($('#floatingSelectPrivileges').val());
    var position = $.trim($('#floatingSelectPositions').val());
    var verified = $.trim($('#floatingSelectVerified').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: URLROOT + '/usersManagement/editUsers',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            surname: surname,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
            privilege: privilege,
            position: position,
            verified: verified
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // Riaggiorna gli utenti
            $(".loadAjax").load(URLROOT + '/usersManagement/listUsers');
            $('#closeExampleModal').trigger('click');
        }
    });
});}
```

Data is sent from a form in a modal populated by another Ajax request that populates a view loaded into those modal

I would like to view the error generated by controls (if they exist) in editUsers function, into modal

This is ajax call that populates modal:

```
function ajaxModalUser() {
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditUser", function () {
    var userid = $(this).data('id');
    // Richiesta AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: URLROOT + '/usersManagement/modalUserInfo',
        type: 'post',
        data: {userid: userid},
        success: function (response) {
            // Aggiunge il response nel body del modal
            $('.modal-body').html(response);
            // Apre il modal
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

}.

here the controller for ajax request for modal:

```
public function modalUserInfo()
{
    $data = [
        'users' => '',
        'privileges' => '',
        'positions' => '',
        'noResults' => ''
    ];

    if (isset($_POST['userid'])){
        $users = $this->userManagementModel->userInfo($_POST['userid']);
        $privileges =  $this->userManagementModel->selectPrivileges();
        $positions =  $this->userManagementModel->selectPositions();
        $data = [
            'users' => $users,
            'privileges' => $privileges,
            'positions' => $positions,
            'noResults' => 'Nessun risultato'
        ];

    }
    $this->view('usersManagement/modalUserInfo', $data);
}
```

and here the page of the view loaded into modal

```
    <?php
require APPROOT . '/views/includes/head.php';
?>
<div class="container">
    <?php if (!empty($data)) {
           foreach ($data['users'] as $user) :?>
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputId" name="id" value="<?php echo $user->id;?>" placeholder="id" hidden>
                <label for="floatingInputId">Id</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <select class="form-select" id="floatingSelectVerified" name="verified" value="" aria-label="Floating label select example">
                        <option <?php if ($user->verified == 2){ echo 'selected';} ?> value="2">VERIFICATO</option>
                        <option <?php if ($user->verified == 1){ echo 'selected';} ?> value="1">NON VERIFICATO</option>
                </select>
                <label for="floatingSelectVerified">Verifica</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputName" name="name" value="<?php echo $user->name;?>" placeholder="nome">
                <label for="floatingInputName">Nome</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputSurname" name="surname" value="<?php echo $user->surname;?>" placeholder="cognome">
                <label for="floatingInputSurname">Cognome</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInputEmail" name="email" value="<?php echo $user->email;?>" placeholder="email">
                <label for="floatingInputEmail">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingInputPassword" name="password" value="" placeholder="password">
                <label for="floatingInputPassword">Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingInputConfirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" value="" placeholder="confirm password">
                <label for="floatingInputConfirmPassword">Conferma Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <select class="form-select" id="floatingSelectPrivileges" name="privileges" value="" aria-label="Floating label select example">
                    <?php foreach ($data['privileges'] as $privilege) :?>
                    <option <?php if ($user->privilege_code == $privilege->privilege_code){ echo 'selected';} ?> value="<?php echo $privilege->privilege_code;?>"><?php echo $privilege->privilege;?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <label for="floatingSelectPrivileges">Privilegi</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <select class="form-select" id="floatingSelectPositions" name="positions" value="" aria-label="Floating label select example">
                    <?php foreach ($data['positions'] as $position) :?>
                        <option <?php if ($user->position_id == $position->id){ echo 'selected';} ?> value="<?php echo $position->id;?>"><?php echo $position->user_position;?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <label for="floatingSelectPositions">Carica</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputCreationDate" name="creationDate" value="<?php if(!is_null($user->creation_date)){echo  date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($user->creation_date));} else { echo "--";} ?>" placeholder="creato il" disabled>
                <label for="floatingInputLastUpdate">Data registrazione :</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputLastUpdate" name="lastUpdate" value="<?php if(!is_null($user->last_update)){echo  date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($user->last_update));} else { echo "--";} ?>" placeholder="ultimo aggiornamento" disabled>
                <label for="floatingInputLastUpdate">Ultima modifica :</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputLastLogin" name="lastLogin" value="<?php if(!is_null($user->last_login)){echo  date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($user->last_login));} else { echo "--";} ?>" placeholder="ultimo login" disabled>
                <label for="floatingInputLastLogin">Ultimo login :</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    <?php endforeach;
    }?>
</div>
```

I tried many solutions, but I can't understand how send the error to the view of the modal and reloading it into modal.

Thanks to everybody

Comment: I would suggest reading about [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (with the emphasis on *minimal*). There is currently a lot of code to sift through and no clear sign where things are going wrong. Do some basic debugging and try to narrow the problem down.